# One to many table with 3M records

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table in MySQL that contains almsot 3 million records.

The table saves friend information in a user system. So it has many users and even more friends (There is a (soft)max of 2000 per user). I had added some extra fields *name, url, dob, image, registered* which are varchar(255) and dates.
My basic data is 2 int's and 1 varchar(6).

When using PHPMyAdmin it all gets really slow. I have an index on the user ID and the varchar(6) and that's how I query all the friends of a user (which goes well). However, any other operation (or the ones to come) aren't going to be fast.

My options:

1. Remove the double data (Normalizing)
2. Change the datatype for the friend IDs and save it like a JSON blob

So questions;

- When my table is only 2 ints and a tiny varchar, will it still be
  slow with 3M records?
- Should I change my datatype?
- Should I be
  using a different pattern for this friendlist problem?

Edit: To clarify a bit more.

The **Users** are not my actual users, but they are user objects nonetheless. All the **Friends** are a *User object*, but I may or may not already have the *User object*. So I'm using the extra data in **Friends** to show data about it in the list on the Users page.

In the ideal world things wouldn't take so long, in the next optimal world I would only have 2 fields in **Friends** which are `user_id` and `friend_id`. But I can not rely on linking `friend_id` to a User object, I may not have it..

**Users** (has more fields, but for brevity)

```
+-------+---------+-------+------------+
| shard | user_id | name  |    dob     |
+-------+---------+-------+------------+
| nl    |       1 | Bob   | 2014-03-26 |
| nl    |       2 | Erik  | 2014-03-26 |
| de    |       1 | Johan | 2014-02-01 |
+-------+---------+-------+------------+
```

**Friends** (has more fields, see description above)

```
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+
| shard | user_id | friend_id |  name  |
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+
| nl    |       1 |         2 | Erik   |
| nl    |       1 |         3 | Alice  |
| de    |       1 |         2 | Rasmus |
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

nl-Bob is friends with nl-Erik (Is a user)
nl-Bob is friends with nl-Alice (Is **not** a user)
de-Johan is friends with de-Rasmus (Is **not** a user)

Comment: Can you post the table declares? I am  confused as to how a record on this table stores all the users friends.

Comment: No it only stores 1 friend. So a user with 20 friends has 20 records. But I have 19k users..

Comment: As long as indexed it should be pretty quick, but if you have (say) 1000 records per user, each of which contains all that users other details that is a LOT of data. Sorry if I am misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: I have edited my question to show more info.

Comment: If in SQL the whether a user has friends or not you can LEFT JOIN them and still get the user back.  But with the talk of objects this sounds more like an issue with a framework rather than just the database design. The actual structure(s) and the SQL that causes an issue would make things far clearer.

Comment: Uh step zero would be to normalize your design.

Comment: Added the tables. It's more an abstract/design problem, instead of real technical. As you can see my current Friends table has info on Alice and Rasmus, but I don't have that in my User table yet..

Comment: why are you using varchar for user_id? integer would be a better fit.

Comment: The varchar(6) is the shard. I typed that before adding the tables. So yeah, user_id's are INTs.

Comment: That should be reasonably quick for most things (you could argue that the shard should be an integer, with another table linking the integer shard id with the shard name). In what situation is performance an issue?

Comment: Doing anything outside of the index. For example; getting all friends from the NL-shard and order them on registered DESC. It's not a good use case and premature optimization is the root of all evil.. but that's why I wanted to discuss my schema and what else I could pre-emptively do.

Comment: In that situation if the friend names were stored only in the user table then you could have an index on name (so they would be ordered) with the friend_id index on the friends table being used for the join. However with the names on the friends table that is not possible. Possibly best to store unregistered friends on the users table (with a flag to identify them). Storing the details in a JSON encoded blog would probably be FAR slower to do anything with in SQL.